# Laravel Link Two User Accounts

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

Hey all you clever people,

Im a little stuck on a problem with migrations and logic if anyone could give me a hand.

Im wanting to link a User ID to another User Id, Example I sign up to using an email and then I'm wanting to link my account to that original account with a different email, i'm trying to do some logic to make it efficient.

Ive done this so far But im not sure if this is correct

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('link_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('main_user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('main_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('linked_user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('linked_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('link_user');
}
```

Im just not sure what to put in the User Model as both of these are going to be user_id, I might be doing this all wrong thou my brain if fried and not sure if im doing it right

Im hoping that I could do something like this in the end ...

```
$newUser->user()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->user_id);
```

Any help would be great please <3

**Solved !!!**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('provider_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('provider_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['provider_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}
```

Added this to the User Model

```
public function linkedUser()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(LinkAccount::class, 'link_account_user', 'linked_user_id', 'main_user_id');
}
```

Added a Class

```
class LinkAccount extends Pivot
```

{
protected $table = "link_account_user";

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

}

And finally did this

```
$newUser->linkedUser()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->user_id);
```

Hope this helps anyone else, Thanks to @GlenUK for the push in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a many-to-many relationship here, albeit between the same table.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

You will need a pivot table (aka an intermediate table) with two fields, each containing an ID of a record from the Users table (much like you have defined above). Furthermore, you do not need to enforce the foreign keys on the migration table, if you want to keep things simple, as you can do it on the User model, via the `belongsToMany()` method.

You will need to pass in the foreign key, as you are doing many-to-many relationship between the same table, Laravel won’t be able to work it out.

You will then be able to interact using the standard methods Laravel defined for such relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have updated the main with the solution thank you again.

Comment: @BobHiller You are welcome. If this answered your question, I would be very grateful to have it marked as the answer or an upvote :)